# My bad, accidently copied over 12,000 photos to desktop

Tags: mac, finder

While trying to copy 12,000+ photos onto micro sd card, the photos instead copied to desktop.
I have a MacBook Air with Mojave. It has 2 GHz Intel core i7 and 8 GB of 1600 MHz DDR 3 ram.
The finder app now is using around 100 percent  CPU.

Specifically I can not stop Finder from restarting and using high CPU. If I quit finder it starts right back up. When it does show me a list of photos.  I can't interact with the list to try and delete them. I am wondering if there might be a safe mode like in Windows to be able to move all photos to a single folder as now they are all opened individually.

Comment: Are you able to open a terminal window?

Comment: yes. It is open

Comment: Tom - to flag someone in a reply, use @ then their name - otherwise they may never see your reply - in this instance @Ramhound will notify him for you.

Comment: @Tetsujin - Saw it purposefully didn’t reply because of the answer

Comment: @Ramhound - cool. tbh, if it was a dragged export from the Photos.app to the wrong place, they could all just be binned & start over. Bit of a non-issue really ;)

Answer (score 1):

"trying to copy"… from where?

If you hover over the copy Notification, an Ⓧ will float into view.
Click it to stop.

If it was an actual copy, just delete the ones that copied so far. If it was a Move, then hit Cmd/Z to undo. [This is dependent on my opening question.]

BTW, Mac checks the copy will fit before it starts, so if you've had to wait too long & it's now finished, you should still be OK for storage space - just make sure you know whether it was a copy or a move. If you've gone on to do other things after a move, then Cmd/Z won't work; it can only undo the last few things you did, in sequence [max 20 steps].

Comment: Thanks for the reply. All of the photo's copied to the desktop. I was unable to delete them or create a folder to place them in.. Apparently the CPU is slammed with too many requests from Finder.

Comment: Then let it finish & let Spotlight finish indexing them all. A copy should in no way impact the Mac's ability to do any other task, unless you're tight against maximum storage, causing active processes to run out of swap space. [BTW, you still didn't tell me *from where?*]

Comment: Sorry I was copying from photos to removable drive to offload from the computer.

Comment: I am able to open a terminal window.

Comment: I can access my terminal

Comment: "copying from photos" you mean exporting from the app or taking them out of the Photos Library manually?? You need to be specific. I still cannot figure out why this would upset the finder, so I'm obviously not yet understanding your method or result.